# perl passing folder name is not working correctly

Tags: perl

I am building a script that receives a folder path as an input.

This is my folder structure:

```
X/bin/
X/bin/myscript.pl
X/data/
X/data/myfolder
```

I open the terminal at the folder `bin` and call my script as this:

`perl myscript.pl ../data/myfolder`

so as you see, I give input which is the relative path to my folder

but when I check if that directory exists (which it does) using this code:

```
-f $folderpath
```

I get false

#### my question

how can I enter the path to my folder?

#### Hint

In myscript.pl I already add the path to folder `X` to my @INC

Thank you

Comment: `@INC` is only used by `require` (which is used by `use`) and `do`.

Comment: [Answer to your deleted question](https://pastebin.com/VRsQc0UZ)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `-f` checks that you have a plain file. A directory is not a plain file.
- The check `-e` would test for existence of some file system object, including directories.
- The check `-d` would test that you have a directory.

For details on the file test operators, read [`perldoc -f -X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).